# pick value from text box whose id generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pick the value from the text box.

Text box id data-id data-phase data-project is dynamically generated.

```
<input class="addinformation" type="text" data-id="" data-phase="1_2" data-project="1" value="" style="width: 50%;" id="IMxyz_addinfo">
```

My js code is

```
var TktNo ="IMxyz";
```

Method 1:

```
console.log($(".additionalInfoBox").find("[data-id='" + TktNo + "']").html());
```

Method 2

```
console.log($("#" + TktNo + "_addinfo").val());
```

Both are failing....any idea

```
console.log("1 " + $(".addinformation").val());
console.log("2 " + $(".addinformation").find("[data-id='" + TktNo + "']").val());
console.log("3 " + $("#" + TktNo + "_addinfo").val());
console.log("4 " + $('input#' + TktNo + '_addinfo').val());
```

output is

```
1 
2 undefined 
3  
4
```

when i do console.log($(".addinformation"));
following are the snap shot
[image]
[image]

Comment: actually there can be many textboxes...so i need to pick value using data-id or id.

Comment: what does it say? error/ no output.

Comment: no o/p for the first method and undefined for 2nd one

Comment: can you please paste more code?? which shows when you are calling for `consolg.log()`

Comment: Can you give more code. what is `additionalInfoBox` element?

Comment: <input class="addinformation" type="text" data-id="" data-phase="1_2" data-project="1" value="" style="width: 50%;" id="IMxyz_addinfo">

Comment: The input HAS NO VALUE... 1, 3 and 4 all worked.

Comment: i typed the value in input box...it didnt give any value

Comment: And did you capture the value before or after you typed? I am going to take a wild guess at before :)

Comment: what u mean....i dnt get you

Comment: You need to capture the value of the input after it's been typed into or it will just log an empty value to the console :)

Comment: see value is coming when i do console.log($(".addinformation"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$('input#'+TktNo+'_addinfo');
```

Comment: glad you sorted it out champ :)

Answer (score 3):

I've coded it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZggHZ/. (Used alert just to test)

```
var TktNo ="IMxyz";

alert($('input.addinformation#'+TktNo+'_addinfo').val() 

);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log($("#" + TktNo + "_addinfo").val());
```

should return the value. make sure this is called after the html is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing here ? The class of your input field is `addinformation` and in your first method you are using some other class (additionalInfoBox) to select the element. It wont work. If there is only one input with the class `addinformation` , then this should work :

```
console.log($(".addinformation").val());
```

Comment: bye the way one question, did you typed anything to the text input before running this javascript code ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
console.log($("input.addinformation").val());
```

Or

```
var TktNo ="IMxyz";
console.log($("input#" + TktNo + "_addinfo").val());
```